# Sharepoint 2016 profilepicture problems on My site pages

Tags: sharepoint, mysite, profile-picture

we are upgrading from SP2013 - SP2016.
Our master page for my site pages has not changed.
The profile picture is showing up fine on person.aspx, but not on any other pages under my site.

Code from master page:

```
<div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList ms-mysite-sideNavBox">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPlaceHolderProfileImage" BlockElement="true" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">
    <SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage CssClass="ms-profile-image" ID="PictureUrlImage" ShowPlaceholder="TRUE" RenderProfileLinks="TRUE" PropertyName="PictureUrl" ImageSize="Large" runat="server" />
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
...
```

person.aspx, default.aspx etc. has:

```
  <SPSWC:ProfilePropertyLoader id="m_objLoader" LoadFullProfileOfCurrentUser="true" runat="server" />
```

All pages under my site are showing the profile picture in our SP2013 solution.
The problem is the same in other master pages like mysite15.master.

[image: Snip from person.aspx]
[image: Snip from default.aspx]

What makes person.aspx diff. from the other pages?

Comment: Check the network requests and see where the http request for image is going, when migrating the profile db will be pointing to old url

Comment: The network request shows the loading of the profile picture for the page person.aspx, but not for default.aspx or other pages.

Comment: Are the urls pointing to correct location? like the new server urls?
check your user profile service for the profile picture property value

Comment: Yes, the urls are correct. Everything works fine, except for the profile pictures not showing. person.aspx is getting the picture from the correct url.